# SQL indexes on a join table

Tags: sql, indexing, join

Let say I have 3 tables : `tbl_posts` and `tbl_tags`, and a joining table for many to many relationship : `tbl_posts_tags` with only 2 columns : `post_id` and `tag_id`.

Does it makes sense to use a **primary key** (post_id, tag_id) and a (unique?) **index** (tag_id, post_id).

Comment: Do you mean primary key? Yes it makes sense!

Comment: It makes sense to have primary key. I don't think creating same index to columns already present in primary key will make any sense.

Comment: I know columns order maters on index but on this specific case I wonder what are the pros and cons.

Comment: Depends on tags distribution. If you have plenty of tags and each tag usually has only few posts attached and you need often to query by tags then yes, adding index by (tad_id, post_id) makes sense. If tags are generic and say third or half of the of posts have same tag attached, then probably not.

Comment: The index column order does matter, so maybe it's worth you doing some testing to see which ordering is better. I'd expect that only the index with the greatest selectivity will ever be used if you add both (use sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean should you make your primary key the clustered index, then yes. Adding an additional index after that would be pointless though.